# How can I conditionally run code if a Gradle plugin is applied?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a script plugin that I would like to:

- Check if the `ivy-publish` applied (via `apply plugin: ivy-publish`):
- If it is applied, declare `publishing { repositories { ivy { } } }`
- If it's not applied, run some other code

However, I'm unsure of how to actually run code if the `ivy-publish` plugin is applied, and I couldn't find anything about that in the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html). Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the [`PluginManager.withPlugin(String id, Action<? super AppliedPlugin> action`)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/PluginManager.html#withPlugin(java.lang.String,%20org.gradle.api.Action)) method. From the Javadoc:

> If a plugin with the specified ID has already been applied, the supplied action will be executed immediately. Otherwise, the action will executed immediately after a plugin with the specified ID is applied.

In your build script you could do something like:

```
pluginManager.withPlugin('ivy-publish') {
  // Do configuration
}
```

Comment: While both answers are helpful, this one actually wound up being more useful for what we were doing, so I've chosen to accept this.

Comment: actually I don't see that this works when writing your own plugins but is evaluated too early, i.e. no project is found and nothing is applied

Answer (score 5):

You can always use [`findPlugin`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/PluginContainer.html#findPlugin(java.lang.String)):

```
println project.plugins.findPlugin('ivy-publish')
```

Comment: There's a problem with `findPlugin` - if a plugin is applied later in the script `findPlugin` will fail to find it.

Comment: @jannis check it in `afterEvaluate` then.

Comment: If there are at least two plugins doing this there's really no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Or use:

```
if (project.getPluginManager().hasPlugin("ivy-publish")) {
    ..
}
```

Comment: The same problem as in [@Opal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46212647/4494577) - this is an eager API.